# На чем лично Вы учили Django

Tags: python, django

Всех с добрым утром! Решил выучить Django, но столкнулся с проблемой, что по книгам, именно джанго учить желание мало. Решил посмотреть видеоуроки, но из-за их давности они не всегда помогают. Хотел бы спросить у вас совета. Какую бы вы книгу посоветовали и почему именно ее.

Comment: Лично я ни книг не читал, ни видеоуроков не смотрел, ни по Джанго, ни вообще по программированию  Только конкретные задачи, просмотр отдельных статей, ответов на en/ruSO и исходников разных проектов. А мотивирует наличие пламенного желания реализовать какой-то свой проект/стартап или горящие сроки на работе  Да, Джанго реально кажется запутанным поначалу, особенно после какого-нибудь Фласка. Но стоит заметить, что с опытом начинаешь понимать все эти нюансы и их пользу для крупных проектов; до этого славного момента советую просто зубрить или хотя бы смиренно копипастить.

Comment: Однако вопрос [не соответствует правилам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), поэтому голосую за закрытие. К слову, для обсуждений и подобного [есть чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).